# Cakephp How to change database connection

Tags: cakephp

I have 2 controllers, ContentController for general user and ManageController for administrator. I need to change the connection from default to admin and I have this code in my database.php

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    public $default = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'user',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'ComputerScience',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );

    public $admin = array(
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'admin',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'ComputerScience',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
    );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

So, inside your Model, you would use the useDbConfig Attribute:

```
class Example extends AppModel {
    public $useDbConfig = 'admin';
}
```

Inside your Controller, simply use:

```
$this->ModelName->useDbConfig = 'admin';
```

Thats all.

Comment: how to change all models instead of 1 model ?

Answer (score 6):

I would use [`Model::setDataSource()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelsetDataSource) rather than just setting the database config var. This is because there are other possible changes that come with changing the datasource:

```
$this->Model->setDataSource('admin');
```