# Is it fine to instantiate models for tables for which model files are not created

Tags: php, cakephp

There are more than 300 tables in our cakephp application. Initially i used to create a model file for each of table but later i started to use objects of existing thin models, for operating on tables which are not used frequently or which are not that important from implementation of business logic point of view.

I work like this.

```
$resumes = new Profile('','resumes','connectionName');
or
$resumes = new Profile(20,'resumes','connectionName');

$resumeData = $resume->read();
```

this works for me and I get rid of creating files which remain without any code, but I am curious to know if it break any convention or design patterns.

Answer (score 2):

### You don't need to create model files

You can instanciate models, whether the file exists or not, using the class registry:

```
$inst = ClassRegistry::init('Resume');
```

This will return you an instance of `AppModel` - using the table `resumes`.

### Don't use `new ModelName`

It's not normal to write `new ModelName` - use any of the existing means of creating models instead (ClassRegistry::init, $uses, associations).

Comment: thanks, but how could i set datasource with ClassRegistry::init();

Comment: There are ways to switch between datasources dynamically. Like for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109994/cakephp-how-to-change-database-connection

Comment: we have about 5 connections.

Comment: we have multiple databases, of which one is in use for application proper, a slave for read intensive operations, others are in use for analytics, recommendations, archives etc which we rarely use in main application, but some times we need some data from these DBs too and at that time i make connection like this. since model constructor calls Models::setDataSource() and sets attributes like id alias and table, I thought I should not set them manually so paased those values when creating objects.

Comment: id is a property that changes in the course of using models. Alias and table don't normally change for a given model instance - and would be set correctly from the class registry init call. There's absolutely nothing wrong with calling [setDatasource](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L3463-L3489) - it's the [equivalent of what happens on construction anyway](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L711-L713). I recommend doing things "the normal way" until you have a reason not to (right now you don't) =).